# Automation out of the box?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, automation

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

I have been recently learning python with the goal of learning more about network automation, I can copy, paste, tweak and adjust a simple script to automate an SSH connection and run some commands to a already "networked" network.

The one thing i would like to automate is  the initial deployment of the network out of the box.

Does anybody know if there is anyway to get a switch (cisco) to maybe pull its config from a attached laptop(acting as a server) is there any initial communication from the switch on boot ?

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources.

Comment: this was a request for resources regarding the above so not sure why thats been removed

Comment: Requests for resources are off topic everywhere in the stack exchange network.  If you get a few more votes you can ask in chat

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: no problems gents thanks or clearing that up

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know if there is anyway to get a switch (cisco) to maybe 
>   pull its config from a attached laptop(acting as a server) is there any 
>   initial communication from the switch on boot ?

Use a DHCP server on your laptop and Cisco's [Autoinstall feature](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/configuration/15mt/fundamentals-15-mt-book/cf-autoinstall.html) or [Smart install](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/smart_install/configuration/guide/smart_install/concepts.html).  Both methods use DHCP options to tell the switch where to tftp its config from on boot.

The specific DHCP server that you use depends on your preferences of course.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [zero-touch provisioning](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9300/software/release/16-5/configuration_guide/prog/b_165_prog_9300_cg/zero_touch_provisioning.html#id_52159) on Cisco Catalyst 9300 running IOS-XE.

Comment: checking it out !

Comment: looks good my plan is to automate a complete deployment of about 60 IOS switches